# Download latest version of file from linux mirror

Tags: curl, wget

Part of my script requires I download the latest version of a cloud image example

```
http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/
```

The current latest is `http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/Rocky-8-GenericCloud-8.4-20210620.0.x86_64.qcow2`

How am I able to with `curl` or `wget` download the latest `.qcow2` file from this link.

Issues being

1. The files name keeps changing
2. There maybe multiple .qcow2 files
3. File must contain GenericCloud

Comment: I had this at hand. More robust, but fails #2. May be useful for someone with a similar question, so I leave it here nonetheless: `wget --recursive --no-parent --no-host-directories --no-directories --accept '*GenericCloud*qcow2' 'http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/'` (Downloads all files with GenericCloud and qcow2 in their name.)

Answer (score 0):

`sort` has `-V` option:

> ```
>   -V, --version-sort
>          natural sort of (version) numbers within text
> ```

So, you can use `curl | grep | sort -V` combination, e.g.:

```bsh
wget "http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/$(
  curl http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/ \
  | grep -Po 'href="\K[^"]*GenericCloud[^"]' \
  | sort -V \
  | tail -n1)"
```

Or if your `grep` does not have `-P` option:

```bsh
wget "http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/$(
  curl http://download.rockylinux.org/pub/rocky/8/images/ \
  | grep -o 'href="[^"]*GenericCloud[^"]' | grep -o '[^"]*\.qcow2' \
  | sort -V \
  | tail -n1)"
```

Comment: How do I attach wget to this? both worked

Comment: Just saw this edit, working good. Sorry I missed one other thing the file must contain GenericCloud

Comment: This most recent change downloads the index.html file